# How do I make a search function for multiple of images in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new in building a html website.

I have many gif animations in a folder. I want to make a search function in javascript so that it can search keyword of images and if an image exist it can display the image, if not exist it will display please enter another keyword.

```html
<form action="#" method="post" id="search">
        <input type="text" value="Type to filter&hellip;" onfocus="this.value=(this.value=='Type to filter&hellip;')? '' : this.value ;" />
        <input type="image" id="go" src="file:///D:/new/index.png" alt="Search" />
    </form>
```

Comment: You can use `<select>` element, `change` event to set `.src` property of `<input>` to selected `<option>` element

Comment: Can I write a code for linking the categories? The code like this: 

<div id="search">

<select categories="" id="sel">
    <option value="1">human</option>
    <option value="2">nature</option>
    <option value="3">wishes</option>
    <option value="4">animal</option>
   </select>
</div>

Comment: What you mean by "linking"? Yes, the HTML appears to be valid.

Comment: For example, I want to make this categories to link like the navigation bar :for example:href="index.html", how do I make this code? Thanks.

Comment: One adjustment at HTML could be to substitute`data-categories` for `categories` at attributes of `<select>` element. You can set `href` of `<a>` element to  fragment identifier `id` `<a href="#sel">`

Comment: Is this code correct? <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<select>
  <option value="human" a href="human.html">Human</option>
  <option value="nature" a href="nature.html">Nature</option>
  <option value="wishes"a href="wishes.html">Wishes</option>
  <option value="animal" a href="animal.html">Animal</option>
</select>
  
</body>
</html>

Comment: No. `<a>` element is not an attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<select>` element with `<option>` element values set to name of image file or full path to image file. At `change` event set `<input type="image">` element `.src` property to `.value` of `<select>` element.

You can link to an element from same `document` or a different `document` using fragment identifier `#id` where `id` is `.id` of element at `<a>` element `href` attribute.

```css
#sel {
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
<a href="#sel">sel categories</a>
  <select id="sel"> 
<option value="cats">Cats</option> 
<option value="nature">Nature</option> 
<option value="city">City</option> 
<option value="animals">Animals</option> 
</select><br>
  <input type="image" id="go" src="" alt="Search" />
  <script>
    var select = document.querySelector("select#sel");
    var img = document.querySelector("input[type=image]");
    select.onchange = function() {
      img.src = "http://lorempixel.com/50/50/" + select.value
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I use another method to search the picture, which I found in this website: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_table.asp , and I just change it to picture and link picture from a folder, but how to put it in a database? @guest271314

Comment: @Sally_2891 Put what in a database? "database" is not mentioned at original Question